# Resampling raster based on mask raster?

Tags: qgis, raster, masking, resampling

I want to resample rasters of e.g. 2 m resolution to the same raster cell size and projection of an existing raster (25 m). However I cannot really find answers how to do it properly. I managed to resample the input raster to 25 m, but this means the new raster grid has its own grid projection/orientation, thus not matching the 25 m raster grid of the masking raster.

Comment: Have you tried "Allign Rasters..." in the Raster menu?

Answer (score 5):

Following comment by @RJJoling, this is QGIS Align Rasters tool workflow:

[image]

1. Click on a green <kbd>+</kbd> icon.
2. `Input raster layer` is the raster you want to change (in your case: originally 2m resolution). Give an `Output raster filename`. Various `Resampling method` are available... , Bilinear or Cubic would be good enough to upscale (coarsen) the grid size.
3. `Raster layers to align`: lists the raster you want to change (from 1.)
4. `Reference layer` is the base layer. In your case the existing 25m resolution raster.
5. `Clip to extent option` is also important in many cases (especially when you need to perform raster-raster calculations).

Comment: Thank you for this detailed description! I used align raster before but for some reasons the new 25m grid did not match the reference 25 m grid. Now with your description it does :-) (I don't know exactly why, but it is working).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the GDAL Tools plug-in. After turning on the plug-in in the Raster menu you can find Conversion/Translate. It is a front-end for gdal_translate which can change resolution too. You can set outsize in percents, you should set 1250% for the outsize.

Alternatively the gdal_translate command line version can be used, where the output resolution can be set using -tr switch.

Another alternative can be found in the processing toolbox (e.g. in SAGA or GRASS group)