# matching up cells in 2 raster layers

Tags: qgis, raster, resampling

I've been trying to get 2 raster layers to match up, so the cells are in the same locations for both layers (they have the same resolution already). But I can't seem to figure it out, already tried the SAGA and GRASS resampling tools with no result.

Comment: Welcome to GIS StackExchange! Have you tried `Align Rasters` tool which is found in `Raster` menu?

Comment: Yes I did, but that just showed 'unable to align rasters'

Comment: Thanks Tim, error messages are helpful. BTW, are they on the same CRS?

Comment: yes they are both in WGS 84 (EPSG:4326)

Comment: I honestly cannot think of any solution. Hopefully an old [example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/277795/84455) works for your case, too.